# How would I show that $34567^2$ isn't a perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been asked to show that $(34567)^2$ isn't perfect, but I have no idea if there is a quick way to do it. I could try listing all the factors and adding them but that seems like its too complicated. Is there a better way?

Comment: Perhaps not what you were looking for, but $34567$ is odd, so an odd number multiplied by another odd number is also odd. There are no odd perfect numbers less than $10^{1500}$. ;D

Comment: $34567 = 13\times 2659$ which are both prime. Checking the sums shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the same answer as the one by Erick Wong. Let $n^2$ be an odd perfect square. The divisors of $n^2$ other than $n$ can be paired as $d, \frac{n^2}{d}$. The sum of the two members of a couple is even. The lonely divisor $n$ then makes the sum of the divisors of $n^2$ odd. This implies that $n^2$ is not perfect.

So perfect odd perfect squares are not perfect. (And even perfect squares are not perfect either, but the proof is different.)

Answer (score 3):

Try showing that it has an even number of proper divisors (odd number of divisors including itself).  What can you then conclude about the sum of divisors?

Comment: the sum of all divisors (including itself) = odd*odd but it should be even (=2n). But how would I show that it has an even number of divisors?

Comment: @kjasgru2346 Hint: every perfect square has an even number of divisors.

Comment: @MJD: **Odd**.. Including the number itself.

Comment: @Inceptio We are talking about perfect numbers here, so we are only interested in *proper* divisors.

Comment: @MJD: True, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\dfrac{1}{a_2}+ \dots +\dfrac{1}{a_n}=1$

If $A$ is a perfect number with divisors $(a_1,a_2, \dots a_n)$.Then equation holds good. What happens when $A=34567^2$?